# Is "Compose" available via IBM's PAAS Bluemix?

Tags: cloud, ibm-cloud, compose-db

I believe "Compose" is now an IBM company. Anybody know if I can access Compose using IBM's free CLoud credits for Softlayer and Bluemix ?

Answer (score 1):

Elasticsearch, MongoDB, PostgreSQL, and Redis are all offered by Compose through the [Bluemix catalog](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/), however you need to a Compose account to bind these services to your application. Compose offers a free 30d trial, and then after that you can find the pricing info [here](https://app.compose.io/signup/svelte).

Comment: The following blog entry shows how to use "Elasticsearch by Compose" in Bluemix, although its using it as infrastructure for monitoring Node.js applications:
https://developer.ibm.com/open/2015/09/20/how-to-monitor-node-js-with-kibana-in-ibm-bluemix/